# I restored a backup from akeeba and lost the latest akeeba backup

Tags: joomla-3.x, akeebabackup

I have 3 backups, one is from today and one is from a week ago. I restored the one from a week ago and don't see the one from today anymore. Is there anyway to get today's backup back?

Comment: Did you delete the site that contains the original 3 backups? If so then you've unfortunately lost "today's" backup. If not, then you can look in `administrator/components/com_akeeba/backup`

Answer (score 1):

The backup is not including old backups, so when you restore an older backup all backups are gone. Only the entries are present in the database, but the backup files aren't back upped. Otherwuse the backups are way too big

Answer (score 1):

You could contact your hosting provider and ask for a ftp + db backup from yesterday. This way you have at least the latest files and data back.

You should always download your Akeeba backups after generation directly and delete them from the server for security reasons.

Comment: ... and ideally not keeping them online on the server I would add.

Comment: Added your hint to my answer, ty.